# How to describe this Ruby on Rails relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two classes in my Rails application. One of them is `Athlete` and the other is `AthleteGameLog`. The interesting part of this relationship is that over the course of many years an athlete `has_many` instances of an `AthleteGameLog`. In the context of the current season however, the `Athlete` should have only one game log per year. So, one for `2013`, one for `2014`, etc.

When working with Ruby on Rails, is the `has_many` relationship still here the right way to go about this? Do I have to write a `scope` in order to retrieve the correct relationship for the specific year I am looking for all `AthleteGameLog` instances on?

Comment: *When* an athlete gets a new log isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 2):

A `has_many` relationship sounds just fine. You might want to add a validation that only allows one `AthleteGameLog` per year per `Athlete` which wouldn't be too hard.

You could write a scope if you choose that takes a year as an input and returns the correct game log. Something like.

`Athlete.game_log_for_year(2013)` for example which will return the correct game log.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitively still has_many relationship. You can write parametrized scope to retrieve correct log:

```
class AthleteGameLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_year, ->(year) { find_by(year: year) }
end

athlete.game_logs.for_year(2014)
```

For those unhappy with scope not returning association proxy:

```
class AthleteGameLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_year(year)
    scoped.find_by(year: year)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, <athlete columns>
  has_many :athlete_game_logs
end

class AthleteGameLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns: id, <gamelog columns>, year
  belongs_to :athlete
  validates :athlete_id, :uniqueness => { scope: :year }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It is worthy add some unique index or unique constraint on athlete_id and year.